# Flying out of Vancouver at 6 am

Tags: air-travel, canada, airports, vancouver, yvr

I have a flight at 6:05 am on a Monday from YVR to SFO in December.

As far as I understand, I need to be at YVR at least at 4:05 am. Assume I don't want to take taxis and also assume I will be staying somewhere in downtown. According to Google Maps, there are some night buses, e.g. N10 from Northbound Seymour St @ W Georgia St that can take me to YVR by 3:47 am, which I need to take at 3:09 am. But this seems to be the last bus; and if something happens to it, the only public transportation option I will have after 3:09 am is Canada Line at 4:47 am. Alternatively, I can take Canada Line to YVR at 1:06 am from Vancouver City Centre and be at YVR by 1:31 am. The difference is just 2 hours.

- Is my assumption that I need to be at YVR at 4:05 correct?
- Am I correct in saying that the above two options are basically the only ones? (Except that I can take Canada Line earlier than 1:06 am and that I can take N10 earlier than 3:09 am.)
- I assume it makes no sense to arrive at YVR earlier (say at 11 pm on the previous day), is that right? People aren't usually allowed to spend night on the airside, but the landside should be ok, right?

Comment: There are hotels with a 24-hour airport shuttle.

Comment: How early to arrive at an airport always involves some personal preference and judgment.  I suppose you're aware that you will have to preclear US immigration and customs at YVR, and including that extra time in your estimate?

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the tip. But if I choose the second option, I may not need a hotel for that night at all.

Comment: @NateEldredge I wasn't aware of this. So do I have to clear US immigration twice, once at YVR, and then at SFO? Also, I don't think that US pre-clearance checkpoints at YVR will be open earlier than 4 am.

Comment: @user77409: No, you clear it at YVR only.  You'll arrive at SFO like a domestic flight and have no immigration formalities after landing.  [More about preclearance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_border_preclearance).  According to [this](http://www.yvr.ca/en/passengers/navigate-yvr/customs-and-immigration/us-customs-and-border-protection) it seems that preclearance at YVR opens at 4:30am.

Comment: @NateEldredge Do people clear preclearance before they go to the secured area/airside? If so, then I guess there is nothing to do between 4:05 and 4:30 if one arrives 2 hours before the flight.

Comment: It looks from the terminal map like you clear security, then preclearance, and then you're airside.  I wouldn't guess that the security opens before 4:30 either, though I don't know.  However, it's quite possible that a line forms before 4:30, and you may want to try to be closer to the front of it.  And of course you also want to include a margin of safety.

Comment: @NateEldredge Regarding the opening hours of security checkpoints, it also looks from the terminal maps that they are open 24 hours. But I don't see preclearance on the map, so maybe we're looking at different maps.

Comment: I'm looking at http://www.yvr.ca/-/media/yvr/documents/maps/2019-yvr_4311_terminal_map_eng.pdf?la=en.  Preclearance is marked "USCBP" and it looks like the security funnels straight into it.  So I doubt the security opens before the preclearance, as you'd pass through security and then be stuck with nowhere to go.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm looking at the interactive map http://www.yvr.ca/en/passengers/navigate-yvr/terminal-maps If you click on the red security marks, then the popped-up window will say that these security points are open 24 hours. Also one answer in [this](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g154943-i81-k6163714-US_Immigration_at_Vancouver_airport-Vancouver_British_Columbia.html) TripAdvisor topic says that you can wait at the door of customs after going through security.

Answer (score 2):

> Is my assumption that I need to be at YVR at 4:05 correct?

Yes, it is always recommended to arrive 2 hours before your flight.

> Am I correct in saying that the above two options are basically the only ones? (Except that I can take Canada Line earlier than 1:06 am and that I can take N10 earlier than 3:09 am.)

Yes, that is correct. In my opinion, the bus should be fine. Worst case scenario you can get a taxi. There are some hotels that offer 24-hour shuttles though.

> I assume it makes no sense to arrive at YVR earlier (say at 11 pm on the previous day), is that right? People aren't usually allowed to spend night on the airside, but the landside should be ok, right?

You're right. It doesn't make sense to arrive that early. Vancouver airport, the Internaitonal airport is open 24 hours and you can sleep there. There is a sleeping guide [here](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/sleep-guide/sleeping-in-vancouver-airport.htm).